# Google charts lose their style when toogle tabs

Tags: javascript, css, charts

I have a tab content here

```
<div id="views" class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'energy')" id="defaultOpen">Energía</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'electricity')">Electricidad</button>
</div>

<div id="results">
  <div id="ajax_loader"></div>
  <div id="energy" class="tabcontent">
    <table align="center">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="chart_div1" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;" class="chart"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="chart_div2" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;" class="chart"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="chart_div3" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;" class="chart"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="electricity" class="tabcontent">
    <table align="center">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="chart_div4" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;" class="chart"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="chart_div5" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;" class="chart"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the respective script

```
<script>
    // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

    function openTab (evt, tabName) {
      // Declare all variables
      var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

      // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
      tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
      for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
          tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
      }

      // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
      tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
      for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
          tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }

      // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
      document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
      evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
</script>
```

In each tab i got 3 and 2 charts respectively, when i draw the chart they look nice in the active tab, but when i toggle in the second tab or vice versa, the charts become small until I refresh them using some tools in the webtool (buttons to recalculate the values in charts). I'm missing or doing wrong something?

Comment: this is the result of drawing the chart while it's container is hidden -- need to wait until the tab is visible before drawing for the first time...

Comment: Thank for the comment. I fixed it redrawinng the charts when toogle tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: I redraw the charts when i toogle tabs.